# check URL exists or throws page not found message in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, validation, http, url, web

I want to validate an url, whether it exists or throwing page not found error. can anyone help me how to do it in asp.net.
for e.g., my url may be like `http://www.stackoverflow.com` or `www.google.com` i.e., it may contain `http://` or may not. when i check, it should return the webpage valid if exists or page not found if doesnot exists

i tried `HttpWebRequest` method but it needs "`http://`" in the url.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
protected bool CheckUrlExists(string url)
    {
        // If the url does not contain Http. Add it.
        if (!url.Contains("http://"))
        {
            url = "http://" + url;
        }
        try
        {
            var request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
            request.Method = "HEAD";
            using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                return response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK;
            }
        }
        catch 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply.. u idea is good, but some sites will be secured where it should have "https://". so how can we differenciate that type with normal websites..

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
using System.Net;
////// Checks the file exists or not.

bool FileExists(string url)
{
   try
   {
        //Creating the HttpWebRequest
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;

        //Setting the Request method HEAD, you can also use GET too.
        request.Method = "HEAD";

        //Getting the Web Response.
        HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

        //Returns TURE if it Exist
       return (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
  catch
   {
        //Any exception will returns false. So the URL is Not Exist
        return false;
   }
}
```

Hope I Helped

Comment: hi.. thanks for ur reply.. i checked it, when i passed a url without "http://" like "www.google.com" its throws this error "Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined." i want to handle this type of problems.